# How to append variable to magic method PHP?

Tags: php

how to append variable to magic method in PHP?

i have object like this `return $profile->hourly_rate;` and i want to make this `hourly` in `hourly_rate` dynamic depends on my variable, here the example:

```
$types = ['hourly', 'daily', 'weekly', 'monthly'];
```

How i can do that? Thanks.

Comment: Something like https://wtools.io/php-sandbox/e2 ?

Comment: Can you provide value of $profile ?for clear idea.

Comment: perhaps you can use magic method `__get()` http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php

Comment: Well, if you make `$profile->hourly_rate = $types[0];` you will get `hourly_rate = 'hourly'`, no? Just assign the "dynamic value" to your object properties, but I'm not sure what you are asking :x

Comment: @AnjaliPatil this `$profile` just example variable :)

Comment: @MickaelLeger the magic method i mean.

Comment: @apokryfos there no way to direct append without define a variable?

Comment: You should use solution from answer below. Just one dirtiest could be probably https://3v4l.org/fLfWX  but avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use property like `rates` which will be array. Then you can access required value as:

```
$rate_type = 'hourly';
echo $profile->rates[$rate_type];
```

In case it is not possible use this code:

```
$rate_type = 'hourly';
echo $profile->{$rate_type . '_rate'};
```

Comment: Good one. Maybe add class Rate for better oop and keep colection/array of Rates?

Answer (score 0):

Mmmmm We don't know what exactly you want. But maybe is something like that?

```
$profile = new class {
    public function setValueType($value, $type){
        $this->{$type."_rate"} = $value;
    }
};

$profile->setValueType(10, "hourly");

echo $profile->hourly_rate;
```